# ? as a logical connective

Tags: logic, terminology, identity, dialetheism, non-classical-logic

I am reading Doubt Truth to be a Liar by Graham Priest. In it he uses the symbol `?` as a logical connective, and I am unsure of it's meaning.

Given his use of `? (a ? a)` to denote the Law of Identity, my first guess would be that it's a stand in for `=`, but the usage also seems to imply that it has at least two parities (1 & 2). I'm stuck.

Here is the full example: [image: Doubt Truth to be a Liar, p.13]

Answer (score 2):

This was a misprint of the pdf. I checked other pdfs of the text and it the law of identity reads "it is necessary that a implies a" in the first case.

If you've got the same rendering of the text that I had, I suggest finding another.

Comment: Ah, man, and here I thought maybe Priest was sprinkling a little bit of erotetic logic into his system.

Comment: This is correct. I have a printed copy of the book and the text is □(α → α). Priest interprets the law of identity in terms of propositions rather than individuals, and his point in context is that the law of non-contradiction can be derived from the law of identity within Aristotle's system, so it is not a first principle. (Page 13)